# Position/orient parent to place child at a particular position/orientation

Tags: unity, c#, transformation, hierarchy

I have a GameObject for which I know its world position and rotation.

From another app, I receive a new rotation and position, which should represent the local position and rotation of my GameObject.

How can I compute the position and rotation of the parent object knowing the (world) position, the (world) rotation, the localPosition and the localRotation of its child? How can I find the necessary transform to obtain the second pair of coordinates from the first pair of coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a parent world rotation\$P_W\$ that takes the child local rotation \$C_L\$ to the provided child world rotation \$C_W\$, we can express that as an equation:

$$C_W = P_W \cdot C_L$$

Then you can simply solve for the parent rotation algebraically:

$$C_W \cdot C_L^{-1}= P_W \cdot C_L \cdot C_L^{-1} = P_W \cdot I = P_W$$

So, `parent.rotation = childTargetWorldRotation * Quaternion.Inverse(child.localRotation);`

(Note that the order of the multiplication here is important - putting the inverse on the left side of the multiplication does *not* produce the same rotation, in general)

Now that we know the rotation, we can work out how that transforms the parent-to-child vector:

`Vector3 worldOffset = parent.TransformVector(child.localPosition);`

And then reverse that vector to find where to place the parent:

`parent.position = childTargetWorldPosition - worldOffset;`

Comment: It worked. Thank you!